# Change editing language in main window of Outlook 2013

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013

In **Outlook 2013** it's possible to answer / forward emails in the main window of outlook, without "popping out" the message to it's own window.

However there are only limited options available during this, what I really miss is to change editing language.

[image]

As you see above there is no option for changing language.

Also I've tried to add `language` to the quick access toolbar, but it's not included there.

Last chance would have been a macro, but I'm not familiar with Outlook VBA and the only thing I've achieved is that `ActiveInspector` is not set when the e-mail is opened in the main window.

Any other solution?

Comment: So nothing is triggered when you begin your reply? Do you have to click on a reply arrow or anything? I don't have outlook 2013.

Comment: Probably some event is triggered, but I can't find out what it is and what is the object containing the new mail. Message being composed is Activeinspector object in Outlook before 2013, and it also works on 2013,but only if the message being composed is popped out into its own window.